# How do I transfer ducal vassals to a viceroy?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I would like to transfer dukes vassalage to a Viceroy, specifically I would like Duke of Leon to be a vassal of Viceroy of Castille. But this option does not seem to come up. I thought you could transfer any vassal to another vassal so long as they were in the right places in the hierarchy. What are the rules exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only transfer a landed vassal of duke-level or higher if you are transferring them to their De Jure liege. In this case, since the Duchy of Leon is not a De Jure part of the Kingdom of Castille, you cannot transfer the Duke of Leon to him.

Whether the title is a viceroyalty or not doesn't affect this.

Comment: I was able to transfer count vassals to their non-dejure viceroy liege.

Comment: @SMeznaric Oops, I'm misremembering. I just tested this and it is Duchy titles and higher.